# Youtube Search list for forMine+publishedAfter

Tags: youtube-api

I get results for these queries:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&forMine=true&order=date&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

and

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&order=date&publishedAfter=2016-10-18T00%3A00%3A00Z&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

but when I use forMine and publishedAfter at the same time I get the error. Is this combination not possible.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&forMine=true&order=date&publishedAfter=2016-10-18T00%3A00%3A00Z&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

> The request contains an invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions. Note that you must set the type parameter to video if you set a value for the eventType

Grateful for any advice.

Oleg.

Answer (score 0):

I also try it in this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it) and I got the same error that you receive. It seems that this error occurs because of the parameter `publishedAfter`.

After checking for another solution, I found this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6666) that you will get that error if you use the parameter `publishedAfter` with other parameter in the [`Searh.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) method.

Just always check this issue if the YouTube Developer have already fix it.